# How access Druid Console

Tags: java, druid

I'm testing Apache Druid. I installed it in a single machine. I followed Druid tutorial: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/index.html

The machine that I'm using is a *virtual machine in an internal cloud access of the company*.

When I start Druid  `./start-micro-quickstart`  it looks like every thing is running well, but when I open Druid console on `localhost:8888`  I got the following message:

> site can't reached

I changed the address to `127.0.0.1:8888`  ==> `same error`.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/druid-console.html) :

> the Router's management proxy must be enabled.

> the Broker processes in the cluster must have Druid SQL enabled.

Then the console should be accessed here :
`http://<ROUTER_IP>:<ROUTER_PORT>`

Can you confirm that those points are valid on your case ?

Comment: I just verified them in apache-druid-0.20.1/conf/druid/single-server/small/router/runtime.properties file I found:

druid.service=druid/router 
druid.plaintextPort=8888
druid.router.managementProxy.enabled=true

The in the broker conf: sql is already enabled: druid.sql.enable = true
In the _common folder I added them also, and I found the druid address is: druid.host=127.0.0.1:8888.

But still can't reach the address. How can I stop druid and to re run it newly ?